Calculate exact difference between dates
I need to calculate days and months between dates, ensuring accuracy when crossing month boundaries.
I assume Wolfram Alpha results are correct so I want the same results from my VBA code.
For example:
The difference between "31/03/1955" and "26/05/2024" should be:

69 anni (years), 1 mese (month), 26 giorni (days)
25,259 giorni totali (total days)

The difference between "30/03/1955" and "26/05/2024" should be:

69 anni (years), 1 mese (month), 27 giorni (days)
25,260 giorni totali (total days)

My code in this last case, starting date "30/03/1955" calculates:

69 anni (years), 1 mese (month), 26 giorni (days) - incorrect, same as  starting date "31/03/1955"
25,260 giorni totali (total days) - correct

Option Explicit

Public Function DiffDate44(ByVal data1 As Variant, ByVal data2 As Variant, dato_richiesto As String, valori_assoluti As Boolean) As Variant
    Dim anni As Integer, mesi As Integer, giorni As Integer
    Dim giorni_totali As Long
    Dim dummy As Date, tempDate As Date
    Dim anniStr As String, mesiStr As String, giorniStr As String, giorni_totaliStr As String, spaziatura As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Convert inputs to Date type
    data1 = CDate(data1)
    data2 = CDate(data2)
    
    ' Handle absolute values if required
    If valori_assoluti = True Then
        If data1 > data2 Then
            dummy = data1
            data1 = data2
            data2 = dummy
        End If
    Else
        If data1 > data2 Then
            MsgBox "ERRORE: Data1 > Data2!"
            DiffDate = "ERRORE DiffDate"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    ' Calculate total days difference
    giorni_totali = Abs(DateDiff("d", data1, data2))

    ' Calculate years
    anni = DateDiff("yyyy", data1, data2)
    If DateSerial(Year(data2), Month(data1), Day(data1)) > data2 Then
        anni = anni - 1
    End If

    ' Calculate months
    tempDate = DateAdd("yyyy", anni, data1)
    mesi = DateDiff("m", tempDate, data2)
    If DateAdd("m", mesi, tempDate) > data2 Then
        mesi = mesi - 1
    End If

    ' Calculate days
    giorni = DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", mesi, DateAdd("yyyy", anni, data1)), data2)
    If giorni < 0 Then
        mesi = mesi - 1
        tempDate = DateAdd("m", mesi, DateAdd("yyyy", anni, data1))
        giorni = DateDiff("d", tempDate, data2)
    End If

    ' Adjust for cases where the months calculation might be incorrect
    If mesi < 0 Then
        mesi = mesi + 12
        anni = anni - 1
    End If

    ' Construct output strings
    If anni <> 1 Then
        anniStr = " anni"
    Else
        anniStr = " anno"
    End If

    If mesi <> 1 Then
        mesiStr = " mesi"
    Else
        mesiStr = " mese"
    End If

    If giorni <> 1 Then
        giorniStr = " giorni"
    Else
        giorniStr = " giorno"
    End If

    If anni = 0 And mesi = 0 And giorni = giorni_totali Then
        giorni_totaliStr = ""
    Else
        giorni_totaliStr = " (" & CStr(Format(giorni_totali, "#,###")) & " giorni totali)"
    End If

    ' Return requested output
    Select Case dato_richiesto
        Case "anni"
            DiffDate = anni
        Case "mesi"
            DiffDate = mesi
        Case "giorni"
            DiffDate = giorni
        Case "giorni_totali"
            DiffDate = giorni_totali
        Case "stringa1"
            DiffDate = mesi & mesiStr & ", " & giorni & giorniStr
        Case "stringa2"
            DiffDate = mesi & mesiStr & ", " & giorni & giorniStr & giorni_totaliStr
        Case "nascondi_valori_a_zero"
            If anni > 1 Then
                anniStr = CStr(anni) & " anni"
                If mesi > 1 Or giorni > 1 Then
                    spaziatura = ", "
                End If
            ElseIf anni = 1 Then
                anniStr = CStr(anni) & " anno"
                If mesi >= 1 Or giorni >= 1 Then
                    spaziatura = ", "
                End If
            Else
                anniStr = ""
                spaziatura = ""
            End If

            anniStr = anniStr & spaziatura

            If mesi > 1 Then
                mesiStr = CStr(mesi) & " mesi"
                If giorni >= 1 Then
                    spaziatura = ", "
                End If
            ElseIf mesi = 1 Then
                mesiStr = CStr(mesi) & " mese"
                If giorni >= 1 Then
                    spaziatura = ", "
                End If
            Else
                mesiStr = ""
                spaziatura = ""
            End If

            mesiStr = mesiStr & spaziatura

            If giorni > 1 Then
                giorniStr = CStr(giorni) & " giorni"
            ElseIf giorni = 1 Then
                giorniStr = CStr(giorni) & " giorno"
            Else
                giorniStr = ""
            End If

            DiffDate = TrueTrim(CStr(anniStr & mesiStr & giorniStr & giorni_totaliStr))
            If DiffDate = "" Then DiffDate = "nessuna"
        Case "stringa3"
            DiffDate = anni & anniStr & ", " & mesi & mesiStr & ", " & giorni & giorniStr
        Case "stringa4"
            DiffDate = anni & anniStr & ", " & mesi & mesiStr & ", " & giorni & giorniStr & giorni_totaliStr
        Case "prossimo_compleanno"
            DiffDate = data2 & " (" & Giorno_Settimana(data2) & ")"
    End Select

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Invalid date format. Please enter valid dates."
    DiffDate = "ERRORE Invalid Date"

End Function


Have a look at the datefiff:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function

Adding my own code because other answers are incorrect and want you to believe that duplicates and gaps in results are perfectly acceptable.
Updated: added CountDateOnLastDayAsFullMonth boolean flag to treat end dates that fall on the last day of the month to count as full months  (this will create dup results for some date ranges)
 Public Function DateDiffToText(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date, Optional ByVal CountDateOnLastDayAsFullMonth As Boolean = False)

' expresses a date range difference in years, months and days
' useful for countdown timers or age calcs
'
' Set CountDateOnLastDayAsFullMonth = true if you want end dates that fall on the last day of the month to count as full months
'   - this will create dup results for some date ranges
'
' year calc - counts any complete calendar years between dates + one year if start day/month is < end day/month

' Month calc - similiar to year calc - counts complete months (regardless of days) between dates
'    on the remainder after subtracting complete years + one month if start day of month (DOM) < end DOM
'
' Day calc - based on the DOM - if start DOM <= end DOM then just the days remaining from start to end DOM,
'     else we calc days remaining in start month and add days in end month
'
' By: @DJ. - David Johnston - Burnaby, Canada

Dim Years As Integer
Dim Months As Integer
Dim Days As Integer

Dim StartYear As Integer
Dim StartMonth As Integer
Dim StartDay As Integer
Dim StartMonthDay As Integer

Dim EndYear As Integer
Dim EndMonth As Integer
Dim EndDay As Integer
Dim EndMonthDay As Integer
Dim TempMonth As Integer
Dim TempDate As Date
Dim TempDate2 As Date

  ' split up date parts
  StartYear = Year(StartDate)
  StartMonth = Month(StartDate)
  StartDay = Day(StartDate)
  StartMonthDay = (StartMonth * 100) + StartDay

  EndYear = Year(EndDate)
  EndMonth = Month(EndDate)
  EndDay = Day(EndDate)
  EndMonthDay = (EndMonth * 100) + EndDay

  'Calculate Years
  Years = EndYear - StartYear - 1
  If EndMonthDay >= StartMonthDay Then Years = Years + 1

  'Calculate Months
  TempMonth = EndMonth
  If EndMonthDay < StartMonthDay Then TempMonth = TempMonth + 12
    
  Months = TempMonth - StartMonth - 1
  If EndDay >= StartDay Then Months = Months + 1
  
  ' Calculate Days
  If StartDay <= EndDay Then
    Days = EndDay - StartDay
  Else
    'get number of days remaing in month by getting last date of the month
    TempDate = DateAdd("m", 1, StartDate)
    TempDate = DateSerial(Year(TempDate), Month(TempDate), 1)
    TempDate = DateAdd("d", -1, TempDate)
    
    If CountDateOnLastDayAsFullMonth = True Then
    
      TempDate2 = DateAdd("m", 1, EndDate)
      TempDate2 = DateSerial(Year(TempDate2), Month(TempDate2), 1)
      TempDate2 = DateAdd("d", -1, TempDate2)
    
      If EndDate = TempDate2 Then
        'special case - end date is last day of month - count it as a full month
        Days = Day(TempDate) - StartDay
        Months = Months + 1
    
        If Months = 12 Then
          Months = 0
          Years = Years + 1
        End If
    
      Else
        
        Days = Day(TempDate) - StartDay + EndDay
      
      End If
    
    Else
      
      Days = Day(TempDate) - StartDay + EndDay
    End If
    
  End If
  
  
  DateDiffToText = CStr(Years) & " year(s), " & CStr(Months) & " month(s), " & CStr(Days) & " day(s)"


End Function

Results:

Updated: Results with CountDateOnLastDayAsFullMonth = True


@Dolphin975 - created my own code that should give you the correct results for all date ranges - cheers!

Awesome work, thank you! The only thing I don't understand is why WolframAlpha with this input:
"29/02/2020" - "28/02/2021"
gives 1 year (2020 is a leap year) while your code gives 11 months and 28 days.
Can you add a boolean option in your function to have both options?

Use the rollforward method in wolfram and you will get the same results as me I think

Forgive me, what is "the rollforward method in wolfram"?

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateDifference.html#:~:text=DateDifference%20computes%20the%20amount%20of,DateObject%5B%E2%80%A6%5D

There are many ways to count, even wolfram has multiple options.  If you want no dups and no gaps - use my method otherwise use your own...

@Dolphin975 - added flag to reproduce wolfram results for leapyear

DJ, what to say... Amazing work. In my opinion, your code is now perfect. Thank you very very much.

Sadly, for many samples the day count is one off: 2000-03-15 - 2002-05-14 returns 30 days, but it is 29. 2000-04-15 - 2002-06-14 returns 29, but it is 30.

That's because 3/15 - 3/31 is 16 days and 5/1 - 5/14 is 14 days = 30 days. If you count the other way you will get duplicate results at the end of the month like 3/30/2000 -> 5/14/2002 and 3/31/2000 -> 5/14/2002 both equaling 2 years, 1 month, 14 days. If you don't like it use gustav's code which has the duplicate results and gaps in sequences.

For two dates where the start day is greater than the end day I count the days remaining in the first month + the days in the last month and then count the number of months between them. This produces a consistent sequence of results with no duplicates or gaps. I think this is a correct result especially if you are writing a countdown timer for example.

Sorry Dolphin975 - I thought I was replying to you. @Gustav - You have your way of counting but I don't agree that it is the correct approach given the gaps and duplicates in the results.

@DJ. I tried many samples and I always got results identical to WolframAlpha (which I assume are correct). I actually don't understand why your code (which has a robust logic in my opinion) has different results in the examples by Gustav and not in other cases.

First, I don't have "my way" of counting; my code just follows the rules originally implemented in VBA and Access. Then, as mentioned before, a month is not a fixed count of days, which is what DateAdd takes into account when adding a month to achieve a count that simulates how a human will count years, months, and days. Finally, see my test run of the functions appended to my answer.

@DJ. I think you could add another option to cover all user scenarios: count FullMonths.

@Gustav - ok it appears we both have gaps and dups - it just depends on how we sequence the dates - your code is ok if you keep the first date fixed and vary the second (which would work for age calcs) - my code works if you vary the first date and keep the second fixed  (great for countdown timers) - so I will have to come up with a way to that works in both scenarios hmmm

It would be nice, but not doable as adding and subtracting months are not unambiguous processes because of the varying day count of months (and years as well). Microsoft's DateAdd and DateDiff mimic quite close how humans will count, thus I recommend to stick with the methods of those. If a strict and continous count is needed, count only days.

Your code in this section is incorrect:
' Calculate days
giorni = DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", mesi, DateAdd("yyyy", anni, data1)), data2)
If giorni < 0 Then
    mesi = mesi - 1
    tempDate = DateAdd("m", mesi, DateAdd("yyyy", anni, data1))
    giorni = DateDiff("d", tempDate, data2)
End If

You need to find the number of days remaining in the month of the first date and use that to add to the days in second date. Like this:
' Calculate days
Dim d1 As Integer, d2 As Integer

d1 = Day(data1)
d2 = Day(data2)

If d1 <= d2 Then
  giorni = d2 - d1
Else
  'get number of days in month by setting tempdate to last date of the month
  tempDate = DateAdd("m", 1, data1)
  tempDate = DateSerial(Year(tempDate), Month(tempDate), 1)
  tempDate = DateAdd("d", -1, tempDate)
  giorni = Day(tempDate) - d1 + d2
End If

You then get the expected output
03/30/1955 - 69 anni, 1 mese, 27 giorni (25,260 giorni totali)
03/31/1955 - 69 anni, 1 mese, 26 giorni (25,259 giorni totali)


Thank you very much indeed! That works in my examples.
I'd like the code to return:
for DiffDate("29/02/2020", "28/02/2021", "stringa4", True)
1 anno (1 year)
but it returns: 0 anni, 12 mesi, 28 giorni (365 giorni totali)
and for DiffDate("31/01/2020", "29/02/2020", "stringa4", True)
1 mese (29 giorni totali)
but it returns 0 anni, 1 mese, 29 giorni (29 giorni totali)

The issue with counting in year and month units is that they are not always the same amount of days. I would consider 28/02/2020 -> 28/02/2021 as one year even though it's 366 days. So 29/02/2020 -> 28/02/2021 would be 11 months, 28 days. You need to fix up your year and month calculations (I can't rewrite everything) :-)

It seems you want to calculate using Calendar Months. You may try this code:
Note that there are optional arguments for output to include weeks or fraction of a month.
Option Explicit
Function CalendarMonths(d1 As Date, d2 As Date, _
    Optional Weeks As Boolean = False, Optional FracMonth As Boolean = False)
'FracMonth --> output as Month+fraction of months based on
'   days in the starting and ending month
'Without FracMonth, output is in years, full calendar months, and days

Dim temp As Date
Dim I As Double
Dim YR As Long, mnth As Long, DY As Long
Dim wk As Long
Dim FirstFrac As Double, LastFrac As Double
Dim Yrstr As String, Mnstr As String, Dystr As String
Dim Wkstr As String
Dim NegFlag As Boolean
Dim sOutput() As String

If FracMonth = True Then Weeks = False

NegFlag = False
If d1 > d2 Then
    NegFlag = True
    temp = d1
    d1 = d2
    d2 = temp
End If

temp = 0
Do Until temp >= d2
    I = I + 1
    temp = EOM(d1, I)
Loop

If temp <> d2 Then I = I - 1


If FracMonth = True Then
    FirstFrac = (EOM(d1, 0) - d1) / Day(EOM(d1, 0))
    LastFrac = (d2 - EOM(d2, -1)) / Day(EOM(d2, 0))
    LastFrac = LastFrac - Int(LastFrac)
    CalendarMonths = I + FirstFrac + LastFrac
    If NegFlag = True Then CalendarMonths = -CalendarMonths
Else
    YR = Int(I / 12)
    mnth = I Mod 12
    DY = d2 - EOM(d1, I) + (EOM(d1, 0) - d1)
    
    If Weeks = True Then
        wk = Int(DY / 7)
        DY = DY Mod 7
    End If
    
    ReDim sOutput(0 To -(YR > 0) - (mnth > 0) - (wk > 0) - (DY > 0) - 1)
I = 0
If YR > 0 Then
    sOutput(I) = YR & IIf(YR = 1, " Year", " Years")
    I = I + 1
End If
If mnth > 0 Then
    sOutput(I) = mnth & IIf(mnth = 1, " Month", " Months")
    I = I + 1
End If
If wk > 0 Then
    sOutput(I) = wk & IIf(wk = 1, " Week", " Weeks")
    I = I + 1
End If
If DY > 0 Then sOutput(I) = DY & IIf(DY = 1, " Day", " Days")

CalendarMonths = Join(sOutput, ", ")
    If NegFlag Then CalendarMonths = "(Neg) " & CalendarMonths
End If
End Function


Note that for jurisdictions where a leapling's birthday is considered to be Mar 1 vs Feb 28 during non-leap years, this formula will return an incorrect age on those dates

I'd love to try out the code you provided but it's missing function EOM()

Your code provides the correct result because "one month" is not a fixed count of days.
I have similar functions:
' Formats the output from AgeMonthsDays.
'
' 2020-10-05. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function FormatAgeYearsMonthsDays( _
    ByVal DateOfBirth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal AnotherDate As Variant) _
    As String

    Dim Years       As Integer
    Dim Months      As Integer
    Dim Days        As Integer
    Dim YearsLabel  As String
    Dim MonthsLabel As String
    Dim DaysLabel   As String
    Dim Result      As String
    
    Months = AgeMonthsDays(DateOfBirth, AnotherDate, Days)
    Years = Months \ MonthsPerYear
    Months = Months Mod MonthsPerYear
    
    YearsLabel = "year" & IIf(Years = 1, "", "s")
    MonthsLabel = "month" & IIf(Months = 1, "", "s")
    DaysLabel = "day" & IIf(Days = 1, "", "s")
    
    ' Concatenate the parts of the output.
    Result = CStr(Years) & " " & YearsLabel & ", " & CStr(Months) & " " & MonthsLabel & ", " & CStr(Days) & " " & DaysLabel
    
    FormatAgeYearsMonthsDays = Result
    
End Function

Output:
Date1 = #30/03/1955#
Date2 = #26/05/2024#
? FormatAgeYearsMonthsDays(Date1, Date2)
69 years, 1 month, 26 days

Date1 = #31/03/1955#
Date2 = #26/05/2024#
? FormatAgeYearsMonthsDays(Date1, Date2)
69 years, 1 month, 26 days

The source function:
' Returns the difference in full months from DateOfBirth to current date,
' optionally to another date.
' Returns by reference the difference in days.
' Returns zero if AnotherDate is earlier than DateOfBirth.
'
' Calculates correctly for:
'   leap Months
'   dates of 29. February
'   date/time values with embedded time values
'   any date/time value of data type Date
'
' DateAdd() is, when adding a count of months to dates of 31th (29th),
' used for check for month end as it correctly returns the 30th (28th)
' when the resulting month has 30 or less days.
'
' 2015-11-24. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function AgeMonthsDays( _
    ByVal DateOfBirth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal AnotherDate As Variant, _
    Optional ByRef Days As Integer) _
    As Long
    
    Dim ThisDate    As Date
    Dim Months      As Long
      
    If IsDateExt(AnotherDate) Then
        ThisDate = CDate(AnotherDate)
    Else
        ThisDate = Date
    End If
    
    ' Find difference in calendar Months.
    Months = DateDiff("m", DateOfBirth, ThisDate)
    If Months < 0 Then
        Months = 0
    Else
        If Months > 0 Then
            ' Decrease by 1 if current date is earlier than birthday of current year
            ' using DateDiff to ignore a time portion of DateOfBirth.
            If DateDiff("d", ThisDate, DateAdd("m", Months, DateOfBirth)) > 0 Then
                Months = Months - 1
            End If
        End If
        ' Find difference in days.
        Days = DateDiff("d", DateAdd("m", Months, DateOfBirth), ThisDate)
    End If
        
    AgeMonthsDays = Months
  
End Function

Full code in my repository at GitHub: VBA.Date
Examples
DJ's function may either skip or dupe a day count when the end date moves to the next calendar month.
Here a dupe at day count 16:
Date1 = #2000-04-15#
Date2 = #2002-05-13#

For n = 0 to 33 : ? Date1, n, DateAdd("d", n, Date2), DateDiffToText(Date1, DateAdd("d", n, Date2),1), FormatAgeYearsMonthsDays(Date1, DateAdd("d", n, Date2)) : Next
15-04-2000     0            13-05-2002    2 year(s), 0 month(s), 28 day(s)          2 years, 0 months, 28 days
15-04-2000     1            14-05-2002    2 year(s), 0 month(s), 29 day(s)          2 years, 0 months, 29 days
15-04-2000     2            15-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 0 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 0 days
15-04-2000     3            16-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 1 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 1 day
15-04-2000     4            17-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 2 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 2 days
15-04-2000     5            18-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 3 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 3 days
15-04-2000     6            19-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 4 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 4 days
15-04-2000     7            20-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 5 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 5 days
15-04-2000     8            21-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 6 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 6 days
15-04-2000     9            22-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 7 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 7 days
15-04-2000     10           23-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 8 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 8 days
15-04-2000     11           24-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 9 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 9 days
15-04-2000     12           25-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 10 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 10 days
15-04-2000     13           26-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 11 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 11 days
15-04-2000     14           27-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 12 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 12 days
15-04-2000     15           28-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 13 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 13 days
15-04-2000     16           29-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 14 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 14 days
15-04-2000     17           30-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 15 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 15 days
15-04-2000     18           31-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 16 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 16 days
15-04-2000     19           01-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 16 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 17 days
15-04-2000     20           02-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 17 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 18 days
15-04-2000     21           03-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 18 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 19 days
15-04-2000     22           04-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 19 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 20 days
15-04-2000     23           05-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 20 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 21 days
15-04-2000     24           06-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 21 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 22 days
15-04-2000     25           07-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 22 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 23 days
15-04-2000     26           08-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 23 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 24 days
15-04-2000     27           09-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 24 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 25 days
15-04-2000     28           10-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 25 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 26 days
15-04-2000     29           11-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 26 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 27 days
15-04-2000     30           12-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 27 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 28 days
15-04-2000     31           13-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 28 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 29 days
15-04-2000     32           14-06-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 29 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 30 days
15-04-2000     33           15-06-2002    2 year(s), 2 month(s), 0 day(s)           2 years, 2 months, 0 days

Here a skip at day count 16:
Date1 = #2000-03-15#
Date2 = #2002-04-13#

For n = 0 to 33 : ? Date1, n, DateAdd("d", n, Date2), DateDiffToText(Date1, DateAdd("d", n, Date2),1), FormatAgeYearsMonthsDays(Date1, DateAdd("d", n, Date2)) : Next
15-03-2000     0            13-04-2002    2 year(s), 0 month(s), 29 day(s)          2 years, 0 months, 29 days
15-03-2000     1            14-04-2002    2 year(s), 0 month(s), 30 day(s)          2 years, 0 months, 30 days
15-03-2000     2            15-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 0 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 0 days
15-03-2000     3            16-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 1 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 1 day
15-03-2000     4            17-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 2 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 2 days
15-03-2000     5            18-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 3 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 3 days
15-03-2000     6            19-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 4 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 4 days
15-03-2000     7            20-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 5 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 5 days
15-03-2000     8            21-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 6 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 6 days
15-03-2000     9            22-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 7 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 7 days
15-03-2000     10           23-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 8 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 8 days
15-03-2000     11           24-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 9 day(s)           2 years, 1 month, 9 days
15-03-2000     12           25-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 10 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 10 days
15-03-2000     13           26-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 11 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 11 days
15-03-2000     14           27-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 12 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 12 days
15-03-2000     15           28-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 13 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 13 days
15-03-2000     16           29-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 14 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 14 days
15-03-2000     17           30-04-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 15 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 15 days
15-03-2000     18           01-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 17 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 16 days
15-03-2000     19           02-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 18 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 17 days
15-03-2000     20           03-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 19 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 18 days
15-03-2000     21           04-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 20 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 19 days
15-03-2000     22           05-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 21 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 20 days
15-03-2000     23           06-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 22 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 21 days
15-03-2000     24           07-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 23 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 22 days
15-03-2000     25           08-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 24 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 23 days
15-03-2000     26           09-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 25 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 24 days
15-03-2000     27           10-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 26 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 25 days
15-03-2000     28           11-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 27 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 26 days
15-03-2000     29           12-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 28 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 27 days
15-03-2000     30           13-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 29 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 28 days
15-03-2000     31           14-05-2002    2 year(s), 1 month(s), 30 day(s)          2 years, 1 month, 29 days
15-03-2000     32           15-05-2002    2 year(s), 2 month(s), 0 day(s)           2 years, 2 months, 0 days
15-03-2000     33           16-05-2002    2 year(s), 2 month(s), 1 day(s)           2 years, 2 months, 1 day


Sorry your code is wrong. Those two date spans should not return the same result.

@DJ.: Yes they should, because the dates are ultimo dates. I know it is a bit hard to grasp, but stick to the fact, that "a month" can be 28, 29, 30, or 31 days.

Sure whatever - If you had a countdown timer that didn't change from day to day you would rightly think it has a bug. You need to re-think on how you count by year and month units.

Think of this (just using the months): 3/30 -> 3/31 = 1 day / April = 1 month (days doesn't matter) / 5/1 -> 5/26 = 26 days / so 3/30 -> 5/26 - 1 month, 27 days

@DJ.: That's what confuses you. It is not about a total day count; it's about the count of years and months and then the remaining count of days. If you don't follow that logic, you may end up with absurd results like 7 years, 2 months, -1 day. This is also why DateAdd works as it does: DateAdd("m", 1, #2022-01-30#) -> 2022-02-28, adding 29 days. So, this is calendar rules, not math.

I think you are confused. I realize it's not a total day count but the way you throw away the remaining days from the start date to the end of the month is wrong. Datadd and datediff they have their own rules which are not appropriate in this case ie datediff("m",#01/31/2020#,#02/01/2020#) will say that it's one month yet no one will ever say there's one month between those dates. If you want to express a duration of days between two dates in a natural and consistent way that does not give the same result for different dates you can't rely on dateadd/datediff to give you the answers.

How do you explain your code that produces these results? 2/29/2024 -> 6/26/2024  = 0 years, 3 months, 28 days vs 3/1/2024 - > 6/26/2024 0 years, 3 months, 25 days. How can there be a two day gap?

created my own code that gives correct results

@DJ._ How do you explain .. Again: One month is not a fixed count of days.
